# AWS ECS Autoscaling failing sometimes with terraform created alarm

Tags: amazon-web-services, alarm, autoscaling, amazon-cloudwatch-metrics, amazon-cloudwatch

I have defined a CloudWatch alarm for AWS ECS scale-in scale-out.

Normally it works fine. but sometimes it fails with below error.
500 is the threshold for scale-out. Metric time is every 5 min. and scale-out datapoint is 1 of 2 (means one value exceeds the threshold in 10 min):

> "error": "No step adjustment found for metric value
>   [437.08774491907025, 516.9558339660845] and breach threshold 500.0"

Step adjustment is defined as below:

```
 step_adjustment {
      metric_interval_lower_bound = 0
      scaling_adjustment          = 1
    }
```

Alarm config:

```
datapoints_to_alarm         = "1"
  evaluation_periods        = "2"
  threshold                 = "500"
```

Terraform code for alarm creation

```
resource "aws_appautoscaling_policy" "task_count_up" {
  name               = "appScalingPolicy_${aws_ecs_service.sqs_to_kinesis.name}_ScaleUp"
  service_namespace  = "ecs"
  resource_id        = "service/${aws_ecs_cluster.shared-elb-access-logs-processor.name}/${aws_ecs_service.sqs_to_kinesis.name}"
  scalable_dimension = "ecs:service:DesiredCount"

  step_scaling_policy_configuration {
    adjustment_type         = "ChangeInCapacity"
    cooldown                = "${var.scale_up_cooldown_seconds}"
    metric_aggregation_type = "Maximum"

    step_adjustment {
      metric_interval_lower_bound = 0
      scaling_adjustment          = 1
    }

  }

  depends_on = [
    "aws_appautoscaling_target.main",
  ]
}

resource "aws_appautoscaling_policy" "task_count_down" {
  name               = "appScalingPolicy_${aws_ecs_service.sqs_to_kinesis.name}_ScaleDown"
  service_namespace  = "ecs"
  resource_id        = "service/${aws_ecs_cluster.shared-elb-access-logs-processor.name}/${aws_ecs_service.sqs_to_kinesis.name}"
  scalable_dimension = "ecs:service:DesiredCount"

  step_scaling_policy_configuration {
    adjustment_type         = "ChangeInCapacity"
    cooldown                = "${var.scale_down_cooldown_seconds}"
    metric_aggregation_type = "Minimum"

    step_adjustment {
      metric_interval_upper_bound = 0
      scaling_adjustment          = -1
    }

  }

  depends_on = [
    "aws_appautoscaling_target.main",
  ]
}
```

Comment: If you only have one scaling definition, you should consider using "Simple" scaling instead of "Step" scaling. Step scaling is able to accelerate scaling when higher-value thresholds are crossed. See: [Dynamic Scaling for Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling - Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/as-scale-based-on-demand.html)

Comment: I need to use "aws_appautoscaling_policy" in terraform for scaling ECS Fargate cluster. In that policy_type = "SimpleScaling" is not supported.

Comment: You did not mention Terraform nor ECS in your question. Please edit it to provide full details.

Comment: done , added the terraform code for alarm creation